# I have a problem with Intent in my splash screen

Tags: android, splash-screen

i build app when open the app splash screen working but after 3 second Instead of going to another page, it closes the application

my codes are:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);


    ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.iv);
    Animation myanim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.mytransition);
    iv.startAnimation(myanim);
    final Intent intent0 = new Intent(Menu.this, Fehrest.class);
    Thread timer;
    timer = new Thread() {
        public void run () {
            try {
                sleep(3000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                startActivity(intent0);
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();

}

}
```

Comment: Please add your Logcat.

Comment: The problem is this I do not get logcat in the Android studio and I do not get the error

Comment: does it *crash* or *just close*?

Comment: Just close the app and don't write crash message

Comment: That code isn't going to just close your app without a crash, and if it's crashing, there will be a stack trace in your logcat. Make sure you've selected the right device and process above the log window, and that you don't have any filters that are removing the relevant logs.

Answer (score 0):

for just test purpose remove finish method from splash Activity. and check your another application close or not. if another Activity close then may you use finish method on another activity.

please try this hope it will help you...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView iv;
    private static int splashTimeOut=3000;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);

       methodLogin();

    }

private void methodLogin() {

     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Fehrest.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
            }
        },splashTimeOut);

  Animation myanim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.mytransition);
  iv.startAnimation(myanim);


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know this will be helping you, maybe you can try change your code like this or you can add your logcat error for making error is clear

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.iv);
    Animation myanim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.mytransition);
    iv.startAnimation(myanim);
    // redirect to another activity
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(Menu.this, Fehrest.class));
            finish();
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```